# Inserting emoji into a textarea with vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I am using vue-3 and I like to insert a emoji into a textarea.

I have a EmojiPicker component  to select emojis. It works well.

My problem is that, after I insert a emoji, the textarea shows the text with emoji, but the ref 'message' is not updated with that value.

I have a case where I can't use message.value directly to update the value. I need  to use the ref 'refInputEnvioMensagem'

```
// vue 3 - template
<EmojiPicker
      @select="onSelectEmoji"
/>
<textarea
  ref="refInputEnvioMensagem"
  @input="(v) => (message = v.target.value)"
  :value="messsage"
/>

// insert emoji
setup(){
  let message =ref('');
  let refInputEnvioMensagem=ref(null);

  function onSelectEmoji(emoji) {
   const tArea = refInputEnvioMensagem.value;
   tArea.focus();
   const startPos = tArea.selectionStart;
   const endPos = tArea.selectionEnd;
   const tmpStr = tArea.value || "";
   if (!emoji.i) return;
   tArea.value =
    tmpStr.substring(0, startPos) +
    emoji.i +
    tmpStr.substring(endPos, tmpStr.length);
 
   }
   return {message, refInputEnvioMensagem, onSelectEmoji}
}
...
```

Comment: you have a typo.  in your template it's `messsage`, in setup function it's `message`.

Comment: you will also need to update `message.value` in `onSelectEmoji` function.  "_I can't use message.value directly to update the value_".  There's no clear reason why you can't.  Updating the DOM directly as you see is not reactive.